# How to Navigate from one screen to other screen in Powerapps?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

Suppose I have 3 Categories like **Carpet, Hardwood,Tile** on first screen and I want the details of each Category on second screen and I have details of each category on second screen .when I click on particular category then the second screen should show only the result of selected category.

example-
If I have selected Carpet on screen one then It should show me the subcategories of carpet

Comment: How is the category data being presented on the first screen: a gallery control, whereby you select the category of interest in a list? Or do you have separate buttons for your categories?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are not providing any details, so I will answer without going to much into details.
To go to another screen from a button you set in the OnSelect property "Navigate(*screen_name*)"
You can also add a command to save the ID of the selected item with Set()
Or you use Select(Parent) and then in the other screen you will use GalleryX.Selected to display the selected item